# Select rows that match different values to retrieve common field

Tags: mysql, search, join, criteria

I have table set up like so.

```
id plan_id name rule
1     3    dep    4
2     3    sta    3
5     4    pri    7
6     1    dep    4
```

Readable legend; dep = department, sta = status, pri = priority

The idea is that I want to retrieve the 'plan_id' that matches the specified criteria. I've tried a number of varying queries I thought would work. This is the closest. I'm trying to work out how best to structure the query. Though I want to know is there a better means of writing this query. In some cases only the department might need to be matched. In other cases, I might need to match all three or just two.

In this scenario, I want to find the plan that contains both status and department. I need it to match the status == 3 and department == 4. The code below should return '3' for the plan_id.

```
SELECT o.plan_id AS s_id
FROM `plan_criteria` o
LEFT JOIN plan_criteria pc
ON pc.plan_id=o.plan_id
WHERE (o.name IN ('sta') AND o.rule_match=3)
AND (pc.name IN ('dep') AND pc.rule_match=4)
```

Edit --

A plan could also contain multiple departments/statuses/priorities.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do the join, just do the "select distinct plan_id ..." with the appropriate where clause.  I'd also revisit your logic. Did you mean:

((pc.rule=3 AND pc.rule=4) OR (pc.name='sta' AND pc.name='dep'));

In which case you'd end up with a result set of 3 and 1.

One more edit :-)  Looking more carefully, if the 'name' column really contains values "department", "status", and  "priority" you might want to redesign the table with those as columns.  A query like this really shouldn't be a big deal, you just need to layout the table right.

Comment: I made an edit. For example; I want to find the plan that contains both status and department. I need it to match the status == 3 and department == 4. Therefore, (name='sta' AND rule='3') AND (name='dep' AND rule='4')

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT o_plan_id 
FROM `plan_criteria`  
WHERE `o_name` = "sta" 
    AND `rule_match` = "3" 
    AND `pc_name` = 'dep'
    AND `pc_rule_match` = '4'
```

I would have both together and just use o_ and pc_ in the table to simplify stuff. as long as your tables dont get too crazy